# No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Facing a problem with new Windows Mobile project. I have created a DataSet and added DataSetTableAdapters. Added a query into it and tried to run it and everything worked well. However, when i tried to implement it to my code i get an error
 `No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame`
Where can be a problem???
Here is a code sample:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    Dim username As String
    Dim kiekis As Integer
    Dim EmpAdapter As DataSet1TableAdapters.EMPTableAdapter
    EmpAdapter = New DataSet1TableAdapters.EMPTableAdapter
    username = "Petr%"
    kiekis = EmpAdapter.Kodas(SCANCODE:=username).Count
    Label1.Text = kiekis.ToString()
    ''MsgBox(kiekis.ToString)

End Sub
```

And attaching snippet of error - could it be related to Symbol Status where i get error: Cannot find or open the PDB file?
[image]

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your code but the project setup. It looks like the debugger is looking for native debug symbol files (pdb). For DotNet normall managed debug symbol files are created and used (mdb). You should check your project settings or start a new Compact Framework (SmartDevice) VB project and add your code.

Comment: looks liek i need somehow to download these pdb files, as when i start new project on different .net versions i get same error.

Comment: Is it possible you have VS set to break on all exceptions, and that Just My Code debugging is turned off? I've seen similar exceptions when VS tries to break on an exception somewhere in the framework.

Comment: I found myself a solution. Just reinstalled all VS with all packages, installed newest Microsoft SDK and then there is a need to  configure network setting in your emulator that it could take internet from my network card and it launched:)